# Deploy SpringBoot Api into IIS Web Server

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, iis

I created spring boot api with gradle build. everything working fine in my local.

I deployed angular app in Sites/DefaultsTest in IIS web server. it run in https://example.app.com/app

SpringBoot API base path is '/api'

I want to deploy spring boot api in same windows server machine and should able to access through Angular App globally.

please guide me.

[IIS WebServer Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoMCM.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the spring boot API is a java web application, we don't suggest you directly hosted the java web application in the IIS.

I suggest you could try to install a docker or using tomcat to host the application, then you could use IIS  reverse proxy to redirect the request to that API to get the result.

More details about how host the spring boot application on the docker, you could refer to below article.
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/04/ansible-docker-windows-containers-spring-boot/

More details about how to use IIS reverse proxy, you could refer to below article.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Comment: thanks for your time to respond my question, I will try and let you know.