# deploy SpringBoot + Angular webapp in iis remote server

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, iis

I have a Spring boot application, If I want to run that application locally we can run with spring-boot:run Or by just executing the main class our project is ready to work. But here I want to deploy the same on IIS Server.

I have an angular app, by just adding the path and running ng build --prod is sufficient to run in the IIS but when coming to java I am confused to run the application in IIS.

I dont think so it will work with spring-boot:run as it is using internal tomcat server, But in the IIS how do we need to deploy this application.

i tried it by making package and run it as a service in remote but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly install java app inside of Tomcat or docker. You can see this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/59463209/8684299 written by
Brando Zhang.

P.S. I don't have enough reputation to comment hence I am writing this in answer section instead.